# Is alkyne hydration possible without a catalyst?

Tags: organic-chemistry

As the title says, is alkyne hydration possible without a catalyst at any temperature? i.e. will it ever occur within a reasonable amount of time? (excluding acetylene)

Comment: Generating an unstabilized vinyl cation doesn't seem that great.

Comment: Any temperature? Not pressure?

Comment: Does hydroboration count?